# Image Sequence Classification from folder images

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I have 3164 images seperated 3 folder belong 3 classes

My code is like this:

```py
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf

data_dir = pathlib.Path('/path-to-images/')

batch_size = 3
img_height = 200
img_width = 200

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names # 0,1,2

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(val_ds)
test_dataset = val_ds.take(val_batches / 5)
```

My model is:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'), input_shape=(3 ,200, 200, 3))) #
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,3), kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
 
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(verbose=1),
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        'path/weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5',
        verbose=1),
]
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    verbose=1,
    epochs=50,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

When I run it first, it gives shapes of input 0 not compatible, but I changed the train_ds like this:

```
train_ds = train_ds.batch(3)
```

it gives error as

```
Shapes (None, None) and (None, None, 3) are incompatible
```

I want to classify these images into groups of three (with labels set) separated into 3 classes
I have a problem in my model or in the preparation of my data set, but I could not find a way out.